# Wrong date submitted to Database

Tags: php, date, logging, model-view-controller, cakephp

I have inherited a CakePHP 3 project handling some readings at certain dates. We have an API connected to a phone app that takes the well readings and inserts them to the database.

The readings as well as created by and updated by timestamps work correctly, but in this inherited project they have a separate date column 'reading_date' that is giving me 0015-10-05. The other aspects of the API controller work fine, but this continues to give me issues. I have the code for the add() method below

```
 /**
   * Add method
   *
   * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
   */
  public function add()
  {
    $wellReading = $this->WellReadings->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
      $data = $this->request->getData();
      $this->log($this->request->getAttribute('params'));
      $this->ats_log($this->request->getAttribute('params'));
      $data['reading_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Today'));
      $data['reading_time'] = date('G:i:s');
      $wellReading = $this->WellReadings->newEntity($wellReading, $data);

      if ($this->WellReadings->save($wellReading)) {
        // we're going to add some related info in here so we can return it with the inserted record in the API
        $operator = $this->WellReadings->Operators->findById($wellReading->operator_id)->first();
        $well = $this->WellReadings->Wells->findById($wellReading->well_id)->first();
        $wellReading->reading_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $wellReading->operator = $operator->name;
        $wellReading->well = $well->identifier;
        $wellReading->region_id = $well->region_id;

        $this->set(['success' => true, 'data' => $wellReading, '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']]);
      } else {
        $this->set(['success' => false, 'errors' => $wellReading->errors(), '_serialize' => ['success', 'errors']]);
      }
    }
  }
```

I have removed the UseLocaleParser from bootstrap.php as I have read that his causes issues in older CakePHP versions.

Also, $this->log() does not give me anything, no matter what I try. I have tried to use the data variable, and many different iterations of $this->request->, Params, Attribute, getData, nothing will show up in my error logs.

The ats_log method should take $data and write whatever is in that variable to a separate log file, we had this idea when nothing showed up in the Cake log function, but everything in that file is NULL. Still, the readings show up in the DB, and only the reading_date column is wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have been informed by my lead dev we have to keep the LocaleParser on.

Comment: Is that the actual production code, or are you just testing things? More specifically, do you actually intend to "hard code" the date and time like this, or is it possibly supposed to be sent from the frontend?

Comment: This is the production code I've inherited. At this point I've just added logs to see what is actually coming in but getting nothing. The reading date should be coming from the front end, and then we hard code it into the reading date column. I am very new to CakePHP, so not sure of another way.

Answer (score 1):

So, this code did not show the whole picture after working into the project more.

My senior dev had already changed previous code from

```
$data['reading_date'] = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('Today'));
```

to what I have above. This caused the validator on the WellReadingsTable to throw an error. In the validator, the accepted format was 'mdY'. I am not sure why someone would allow invalid date format into the DB but after switching it to 'Ymd' data is being entered correctly.

Second part, instead of using $this->log(); to capture data, I was able to use debug(); to get data to show up in a separate log in the filestructure.